# Where to put aliases in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm quite new to MySQL and SQL in general and can't fully understand how and where to place aliases.
For examlple I have scheema like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
USE testdb;

CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    value INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    value INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO table_a (value) VALUES (25), (43), (15);
INSERT INTO table_b (value) VALUES (11), (15), (16);
```

And I need to get sum of values of every record(in both tables). For given example it should be 125. My query looks like this

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT value FROM table_a) AS a_value
    UNION ALL
        (SELECT value FROM table_b) #AS b_value
) as total;
```

What I can not understand is:

1. why "a_value" and "total" aliases are absolutely necessary (I never use them in this query) and their absence giving me "Every derived table must have it's own alias"?
2. why "b_value" is making "SELECT is not valid at this position" error for first select? Isn't it also a derived table like one with "a_value" alias?

And I have one question about parentheses and subqueries: why do I need this "SELECT * FROM" to take UNION in parentheses? I started from such request:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM
    (SELECT value FROM table_a) AS a_value
UNION ALL
    (SELECT value FROM table_b);
```

But instead of sum I want it was giving me sum of "value" from "table_a" united with "value" column from "table_b" - [83, 11, 15, 16]. So I tried just take everything after FROM in parentheses and it didn't work out: I got "SELECT is not valid at this position" error.

I wasn't really sure, just tried first that came to my mind and put this SELECT * FROM inside parentheses before everything else and it worked. So I want to know why it works and why my first way (with just parentheses) does not work?

Comment: I'm not quite clear which question it is that you actually want answered

Comment: A UNION's SELECTs do not need any brackets, and no aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All derived tables -- subqueries in the `FROM` clause -- need to have a table alias.  It doesn't make a difference if they are ever used.

However, the subqueries are not needed.  You can put the `UNION ALL` in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(value) as total
FROM (SELECT value FROM table_a UNION ALL
      SELECT value FROM table_b
     ) ab
-------^ note that this is needed although it is not used in the query
```

The alias *could* be used:

```
SELECT SUM(ab.value) as total
```

It might be slightly faster to do the aggregation first in the subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(value)
FROM (SELECT SUM(value) as value FROM table_a UNION ALL
      SELECT SUM(value) as value FROM table_b
     ) ab
```

Comment: It seems counter-intuitive that two (or three) SUMs would be quicker than one, but it does indeed appear to be the case - roughly twice as fast on ca 100,000 rows per table

Answer (score 0):

It is because the result from the sub-query can it can be uniquely identified. You have to do this even if you are not going to reference the name anywhere.

When subqueries are used in a SELECT statement they can only return one value.

In general, the subquery is run only once for the entire query, and its result reused.

Comment: "*When subqueries are used in a SELECT statement they can only return one value*" - that's wrong unless you meant "in the select *list*" (i.e. the list of columns)

Comment: You can refer from this link: "https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-20-using-subqueries-in-the-select-statement/#:~:text=When%20subqueries%20are%20used%20in,query%2C%20and%20its%20result%20reused."